# Align not working -- trouble with large square brackets not being displayed

Tags: formatting, align

When trying to run

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta_0} 
   &=\sum^n_{k=1}\bigg\[ -e^{\beta_0+\beta_1x_k}+y_k\bigg\]  \\ 
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta_1} 
   &=\sum^n_{k=1} \bigg\[-x_ke^{\beta_0+\beta_1x_k}+x_ky_k\bigg\]
\end{align*}
```

The result is instead of two nicely aligned equations this:

[image]

How would I go about fixing this so that two of the four lines disappear and the other two are properly formatted?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you noticed you are getting a lot of compilation errors? You shouldn't ignore them. The main reason is that you are using `\bigg\[` instead of `\bigg[`.

Comment: Welcome! You get many errors from that code. Change `\bigg\[` into `\Bigl[` and `\bigg\]` into `\Bigr]`. The commands `\[` and `\]` initiate display math mode. But simply `[` and `]` would be good as well (and perhaps parentheses instead of brackets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To typeset square brackets, just write `[` and `]`, *not* `\[` and `\]`. Do note that `\[` and `\]` are *control sequences* which initiate and close display math mode. That's definitely not what you should be trying, is it?

You don't need to make the square brackets all that "bigg" --- `\big` suffices perfectly. Incidentally, be sure to write `\bigl[`, not just `\big[`; this will have a major, beneficial impact on how the subsequent unary `-` ("minus") symbol is spaced.

And, to improve legibility, consider writing `\exp(...)` instead of `e^{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta_0} 
  &=\sum^n_{k=1} \bigl[ -\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1x_k)+y_k\bigr]  \\ 
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta_1} 
  &=\sum^n_{k=1} \bigl[ -x_k\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1x_k)+x_ky_k\bigr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```